# Itext rectangle will not bleed to edge of page

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am attempting to modify the background-color of a single page of a multi-page PDF document created using iText.

The easiest way to do this appeared to be by creating a Rectangle the entire size of the page, with the specified background color, and applying it to the page in question using the PdfContentByte utility. (having explored using the Document API, this seemed not to be the best option, since this applied the styling to ALL pages in the document, which I did not want).

When run, on close inspection, I can see that there is a single pixel along the upper, right and bottom margins, which remains white, the rest of the page being the correct color. I have played with the rectangle to ensure no margins were created, but to no avail. Find the code I am using below.

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, helper.getPageWidth(), helper.getPageHeight());
r.setBackgroundColor(Constants.GREEN);

PdfContentByte cb = helper.getWriter().getDirectContent();
cb.rectangle(r);
cb.setColorFill(Constants.GREEN);
cb.setColorStroke(Constants.GREEN);
cb.fillStroke();
```

It seems whatever I try, I cannot get rid of the single white pixel row along these 3 sides of the page. Does anyone have any idea how to bleed to the VERY edge of an `iText` page?

Answer (score 0):

First:Please mention the itext version you are using.I'm currently used your code snippet and made some changes and it work out well.May be full code snippet will help me to find out whats wrong in your code.

(prime suspect to me this line `Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0,0,helper.getPageWidth(),helper.getPageHeight())`)

I've attached the output and the code i used.

```
 package com.pra.itext;

    import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
    import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
    import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
    import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
    import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    /**
     *
     * @author Prajit
     */
public class ItextRect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PdfReader rdrPdf = null;
        PdfStamper stmprPdf = null;
        try {
            rdrPdf = new PdfReader("E:/Head.First.Servlets&Jsp.pdf");
            stmprPdf = new PdfStamper(rdrPdf, new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/Example.pdf")));
            for (int pgCnt = 1; pgCnt <= rdrPdf.getNumberOfPages(); pgCnt++) {
                if (pgCnt == 1) {
                    PdfContentByte pdfCntntByt = stmprPdf.getUnderContent(pgCnt);
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(rdrPdf.getPageSize(pgCnt));
                    r.setBackgroundColor(Color.red);
                    pdfCntntByt.rectangle(r);
                    pdfCntntByt.setColorFill(Color.red);
pdfCntntByt.setColorStroke(Color.red);
                    pdfCntntByt.fillStroke();
                }
            }
            stmprPdf.close();
            rdrPdf.close();
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            System.err.println(de.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use spaces to indent normal text; it makes it show up as code.